# Read numbers(integers) from a file and store it a 2-D array

Tags: c, matlab, file-io, multidimensional-array

I have a file(both .dat and .txt format) which contains numbers(integers) in rows and columns form. I need to read
numbers(integers) from this file. That data is to be stored in a 2D-array. This array is defined in my C program. 
I have tried to use file handling in C to accomplish this, but it is not reading the whole file.
The program stops abruptly at some data in the file and exits the program.
Following is my C code used for this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define EOL '\n'

int main(){

int i = 0,j = 0,array[][];          //i is row and j is column variable, array is the     target 2d matrix 
FILE *homer;
int v;
homer = fopen("homer_matrix.dat","w");   //opening a file named "homer_matrix.dat"
for(i=0;;i++)
  {
   for(j=0;;j++)
    {
            while (fscanf(homer, "%d", &v) == 1)           //scanning for a readable  value in the file
            {
                if(v==EOL)                                      //if End of line occurs , increment the row variable
                   break;
                array[i][j] = v;                                 //saving the integer value in the 2d array defined
            }
        if(v==EOF)
           break;                                                //if end of file occurs , end the reading operation.
    }

  }
fclose(homer);                                                        //close the opened file

for(i=0;i<=1000;i++)
  {
     for(j=0;j<=1200;j++)
        printf(" %d",array[i][j]);                          //printing the values read in the matrix.

   printf("\n");
   }


 }
```

Thanks Guys for the response, But the issue is something else..
 allocated the memory for the 2-d array using the following code:

```
#define ROW 512

#define CLMN 512


for(i = 0; i <  ROW; i++)

  {

    for(j = 0;  j < CLMN; j++)

        {

array[i][j] = 0;

        }

  }
```

Also I modified the permission to 'r' in the following code.

```
homer = fopen(" homer_matrix.txt" , "r");
```

Still, however, I am not able to get the 2-D entries into my variable 'array'.

p.s. The "homer_matrix.txt" is generated using matlab through following commands:

CODE:

```
A=imread('homer.jpg');

I=rgb2gray(A);

dlmwrite('homer_matrix.txt',I);
```

This code will generate the file 'homer_matrix.txt' which contains the grayscale values of the image in a 768 X 1024 entry form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will work for you.
It will calculate exactly how many rows and columns you have in your text file.

```
do {  //calculating the no. of rows and columns in the text file
    c = getc (fp);

    if((temp != 2) && (c == ' ' || c == '\n'))
    {
        n++;
    }
    if(c == '\n')
    {
        temp =2;
        m++;
    }
} while (c != EOF);
fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = 0,j = 0,array[][];
```

The `array` declaration here is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, i have just edited my question with the edited code, it would be great if you could help

Comment: @JimmyThakkar how is your array `array` declared now? Please show the declaration of your array.

Comment: #define ROW 234

#define CLMN 327


int main(void)

{


int i = 0,j = 0,array[ROW][CLMN];   //i is row and j is column variable, array is the target 2d //matrix

Comment: @JimmyThakkar Put limits in your `for` loops: `for(i=0;i<ROW;i++)` and `for(j=0;j<CLMN;j++)` If that does not help, I suggest you open  a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
homer = fopen("homer_matrix.dat","w");
```

It's not good idea to open text file for reading with flag "w". Try to use "rt" instead.

Comment: Edited the code, please look at it if you have any other solution, thanks

Comment: Please, add few lines of your text file to your question or share whole file with dropbox.com or something and I'll try to fix your code according to your data. BTW, are you sure that exporting and parsing of text file is good for you? I think it will be better if you'll export binary file in matlab and then just read it into memory in your C program.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i got the solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to allocate memory for your array

```
int i = 0,j = 0,array[][];
```

This should be something like

```
#define MAXCOLS 1000
#define MAXROWS 1000
int i = 0,j = 0,array[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];
```